# PHP & MySQL - HTMLpurifier and special characters display problem

Tags: php, mysql, htmlpurifier

When I enter the special character &#9763; into my mysql database it turns into `☣` when stored in the database and when I try displaying the results from the database it is displayed as `â˜£` when it should be displayed as `☣` how can I fix this problem?

Comment: What are you using to store it? Most likely something is converting it back before it gets stored.

Comment: What collation do you have on the table?

Comment: what do you mean what I'm using to store it?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command before submitting your commands.

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP docs says using "SET NAMES" isn't recommended. Rather use [mysql_set_charset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php).